# Why does this innerhtml thing go back?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my current code. When I click on the button approve....the html heya changes to fred flinstone, but goes back again to heya in 2 seconds. Why so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function button()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('approve');
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML= 'Fred Flinstone';
}
</script>

<body>
<form>
<p id="p">heya</p>
<input type="submit" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="button()"/>
<input type="submit" id="reject" value="reject"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the submit button causes the page to reload, effectively undoing your changes to the DOM.

If you change the type of the input element to "button" instead of "submit" it will work fine.

```
<input type='button' id='approve' value='approve' onclick='button()'/>
```

Please note that in doing this, the button will not be posting the form anymore.  If that's what you want then you will need to have code on the server side to modify the rendered page to reflect your changes.

Comment: hahah, I've spent an hour trying to fix this same problem.  I love learning to code.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
<input type="submit" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="button(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: just out of curiousity, why make it of type 'submit' instead of 'button' if you are always going to return false? (and therefore never submit the form)